# So when I put my shapes into a collection this happens

Tags: java

So I put my shapes into a collection and it then gets iterated with an enhanced for loop. Could anyone tell me why I'm getting this output?

As the mouse is dragged to the bottom right multiple squares show up.

[image: screenshot]

```
 final MouseInputAdapter mia = new MouseListener();
        addMouseListener(mia);
        addMouseMotionListener(mia);

        myG.setPaint(getColor());
        myG.setStroke(getBrushStroke());

        for (final Shape s : myShapes) {      
            myG.draw(s); 
            myShapes = new ArrayList<>();          
        }

        theGraphics.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
```

my collection

```
/**
         * Gets the next point.
         * 
         * @param theE when mouse dragged
         */
        public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent theE) {

            myX = theE.getX();
            myY = theE.getY(); 

            if (myOldX > myX) { 
                myStartX = myX;
                myWidth = myOldX - myX;
            } else {
                myStartX = myOldX;
                myWidth = myX - myOldX;
            }
            if (myOldY > myY) {
                myStartY = myY;
                myHeight = myOldY - myY;
            } else {
                myStartY = myOldY;
                myHeight = myY - myOldY;
            }

            if (ToolBar.myPencil.isSelected()) {
                myShapes.add(new Line2D.Double(myOldX, myOldY, myX, myY));

                myOldX = myX;
                myOldY = myY;

            } else if (ToolBar.myRectangle.isSelected()) {

                myShapes.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(myStartX, myStartY, myWidth, myHeight));

            } else if (ToolBar.myEllipse.isSelected()) {
                myShapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(myStartX, myStartY, myWidth, myHeight));
            }            
            repaint();
        }
```

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to achieve? My guess is that you do not dispose of the previous shapes/lines when you add the new ones. If you want a single rectangle drawn on the screen, remove the other ones from `myShapes`.

Comment: When is the first code snippet run, that includes the `addMouseListener(mia);` ? Is that code run multiple times, so you add more and more mouselisteners ?

Comment: And mouselistener was in paint coomponent but I just placed in the constructor

Comment: Didn't fix it though